# I can't find the paypal API?

Tags: paypal

I'm in third-party applications (like PA), now want to join up ebay, so need to paypal user authorization. Such as user already through paypal give me the authorization of the API (Add New Third Party Permissions), How to through the user's paypal account, I get the user is authorized to me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is  a paypal developer support question and should be asked directly at their site.

Comment: I really can't find the answer

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has lots of different APIs depending on what you're after.  I would take a look at this for a [list of all the Classic APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/), which are what you would use when working with a client who has granted API permissions for you.

For more details about the different PayPal products which utilize the individual APIs you can [view the integration guides](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/).